# How to get the previous anonymous user id when a user logs in ASP.NET Membership?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership

I'm hoping someone can point me to the right events or methods to hook into to get a user's Anonymous Id (from Context.Request.AnonymousID) before they login in ASP.NET's Membership Providers.  The behavior I have seen is that this value gets sets to the registered/logged-in user's userid after they login.

I have tried setting a cookie in Profile_OnMigrateAnonymous(object sender, ProfileMigrateEventArgs args) on the Global.asax and that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation suggests that this is not the case.  In fact, it says specifically that you have to clear the cookie explicitly when the user is logged in, or else it will be persisted.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.anonymousid.aspx

Are you setting the identifier in the `AnonymousIdentification_Creating` method?

And are you using the following in your web.config?

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />
```